# Wait for the loop to finish before performing the next action

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, async-await

I have the following loop that is fetching data and then store it into the `allVegetables` variable. I need the loop to finish before I can log the length of the array. With the below code I get zero for the length of `allVegetables`

```
var allVegetables = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  //fetch the next batches of vegetables
  fetch(`https://www.nofrills.ca/api/category/NFR001001002000/products?pageSize=48&pageNumber=${i}&sort=title-asc`, {
    "headers": {
      ...      
    },
    "referrer": "https://www.nofrills.ca/Food/Fruits-%26-Vegetables/Vegetable/c/NFR001001002000?sort=title-asc",
    "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "body": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "mode": "cors"
  }).then(
    function (response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      response.json().then(function (data) {
        //ad the results of the data to the array
        allVegetables = allVegetables.concat(data.results);
      });
    })
};

console.log("number of vegetables are:", allVegetables.length);
```

Currently the logs give me zero which I assume it is because it is not waiting for the loop to finish filling up the array `allVegetables`. I also assume I should use async but I am a newbie and cant figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store all the fetch requests, and their results in an array. This will result in an array of promises. With these promises you can wait for all of the to finish with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and handle the output of all the responses in a single go and store them all in the `allVegetables` variable.

Because you'll end up with an array of array use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to create a single array with all the values which you can assign to your `allVegetables` variable.

```
let allVegetables = [];
let iterations = 10;

const requests = Array(iterations).fill().map((_, i) => fetch(`https://www.nofrills.ca/api/category/NFR001001002000/products?pageSize=48&pageNumber=${i}&sort=title-asc`, {
  "headers": {
    ...      
  },
  "referrer": "https://www.nofrills.ca/Food/Fruits-%26-Vegetables/Vegetable/c/NFR001001002000?sort=title-asc",
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors"
}).then(response => {
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error('Looks like there was a problem with request ${i}. Status Code: ' + response.status);
  }
  return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  return data.results;
});

const responses = Promise.all(requests).then(data => {
  allVegetables = [...allVegetables, ...data.flat()];
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Reading through it everything makes sense but when I run it doesnt work. 1. I am looking to get only an array called `results` from the fetch which is why I had it written as `data.results` how do I make that happen in your code? something like `return response.results.json();` but it doesnt seem right. I should get in total 193 but right now with yours it gives me 10

Comment: I've overlooked your first point. This is fixed by adding another `then` callback to the promise chain which simply returns the `results` property at the end of the promise. In the loop in your example you iterate 10 times. You can adjust this by changing the value of the `iterations` variable to 193.

Comment: that fetch needs to be done only 10 times. In each 10 times; there is an array called results in the response data that contains up to 48  products in it.  when I said 193; I meant 193 products. Basically at one point the fetch returns empty `results` within the fetch. So I thin I dont need to do the `iteration` here. Gonna try it now

Comment: Quick question. if I want to have 3-4 more fetches done (different fetches) before adding to the `allVegetables` how would I fit that in there?. .. the other fetches have different url completely

Comment: If those request don't need any data from each other, like fetch 2 needs the result of fetch 1, then you could alter the loop to collect all the fetch requests in a single array and add those other 3-4 request to that same array before the loop in my answer. That requires you to rewrite it back to a regular `for` loop and `push` the fetches in an array. If they do need each others result you would need to call the next fetch in the `then` callback of the fetch before that.

Comment: would it be something like this: `const responses = Promise.all(requests, requests2, requests3, requests4,..).then(data => {`

Comment: Well, yes exactly something like that. But beware of the types as the `requests` value is in this case an array. If the others are too you'll need to concatenate. If not, write it like this: `Promise.all([...requests, requests2, requests3, requests4])`. `Promise.all` accepts an array of promises.

Comment: they are not dependent on each other. And they all have the same outcome as this one here. Then I should write different fetches like `const requests2 =..` , `const requests3 =..`, `const requests4 =..`,  and more...

Comment: oh; so since they have the same outcome; you are saying I should concatenate it? how would that look in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could store all your fetch promises inside an array and then use Promise.allSettled to wait for them to finish their work.

Here is a quick example:

```
const responses = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  responses.push(
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then(response =>
      response.json()
    )
  );
}
Promise.allSettled(responses).then(console.log);
```

That will log an array of objects with this shape:

```
{
  status: 'string',
  value: Object
}
```

Being the 'value' attribute the one containing the information retrieved from the fetch.

In your case you would simply have to check the length of your array.

You can check the example on a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-currying-r395s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by a) adding code to illustrate and b) adding a warning that Promise.allSettled is a esnext feature.